# what is "multidimensinal data" in business intelligence?

Tags: java, rdbms, olap, business-intelligence

I'm try to understand what the BI and OLAP is.

from wikipedia, says:

> OLAP tools enable users to analyze multidimensional data interactively from multiple perspectives

After a lots of Google, here is my understand:

"multidimensianl data" means data in a multidimention model, it's diff to rational data model which store data in a "table" or tables, table can be think as a 2D data model, multidimention data model ussually use 3D structure like a "cube" to store data.

Comment: When you googled for "what is multidimensional data", which part of the answer was missing? Narrow down your question to precisely what is bothering you.

Comment: Well.. OLAP tools enable users to analyze multidimensional data interactively from multiple perspectives.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, and as such isn't suitable for this site.

Comment: @NPE It could be a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" if it was more specific.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I agree. That's why I did not vote to close the question.

Comment: Otherwise, it might well suit http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you completely don't understand a concept, how could you wide up or narrow down it?

Comment: By googling it out and getting informed, how else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Multidimensional data" means each record has keys in it.
e.g. A customer in retail shop has birthday, gender, address, shopping list, etc.

The way multidimensional data is indexed and processed is little different than conventional rdbms techniques.

Typically BI and OLAP tools provide optimized way to query multidimensional data.
e.g. customer residing in 2km vicinity(derived from address) who bought milk at-least 5 times in last month.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OLAP but "multidimensional data" usually means you're looking at some data which has n properties.

E.g. a person could have a birthdate, a name, a home town, a job...

Or a road could have a length, some geo locations, ...

Comment: I feel like that might be a poor example since birthdate, name, hometown, job would all probably be attributes of a single Person dimension.  Perhaps a better example would be if you have a sales database, you could have a date, customer, product all related to a sale. This would be 3 dimensions related to a sales fact.